# Xamarin forms button with no border issue

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I try to render a list of clickable items in a view. I would like to add a button with an image and a white border (the first one). I discovered that the buttons in my StackLayout/ViewCell can't render a border.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage 
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XLabs.Forms.Controls;assembly=XLabs.Forms"
x:Class="*.PlacesPage"
Title="TEST">
<ContentPage.Padding>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="0, 20, 0, 0" />
</ContentPage.Padding>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="lvPlaces" ItemsSource="{Binding Places}" SeparatorColor="Gray" SeparatorVisibility="Default" RowHeight="120" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Button HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" BorderWidth="3" BorderColor="White" Text="IMG"></Button>
                            <Button Text="{Binding Name}" BorderWidth="0" FontSize="20" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="OnButtonClickedPlace"></Button>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                  </ViewCell>
              </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using Android? If yes, then:

> On Android this property will not have an effect unless
>   VisualElement.BackgroundColor is set to a non-default color.

Comment: you nailed it!!

Answer (score 20):

I'm using Xamarin.Forms 2.3, and I was also trying to create a button, with no border radius, a background color set to white, and a border color & width, and none of the above answers worked for me.

Actually I still had to set the BorderRadius to 1 (my width was 2), AND add another workaround that I just cannot understand :

In my Android project, I added a Custom renderer, for Button, with nothing in it. Absolutely nothing.
So the behavior of Xamarin forms, is different on Android when you use the Default renderer, and when you use a custom renderer that inherits from the default renderer, and yet with no line of code in it.

My Renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Button), typeof(GenericButtonRenderer))]

    namespace Express.CustomRenderers
{
    public class GenericButtonRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ButtonRenderer
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Had the same problem. This was the only thing that worked in 2.3. Thanks!

Comment: This also fixes the problem when you want to remove the shadow and make the button appear completely transparent in XF 2.3

Comment: worked perfect for me.  Crazy that we have to do this.

Comment: Wouldn't ever come up with this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: this is due to the fact that you are using **FormsAppCompatActivity** which registers the following renderer 
*Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android*.**AppCompat**.ButtonRenderer* instead of *Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ButtonRenderer*

Comment: Though this will show an alert for being obsolete, it still works for last version Xamarin.Forms (2.5.0.121934)

Answer (score 13):

There seems to be a issue in Xamarin.Forms where [`Button` borders don't show on Android when the `ButtonRadius` is 0](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/23039/button-bordercolor-not-showing-on-android-4-4). (It doesn't appear that this issue is fixed as of Xamarin.Forms v2.0.0.6482.) It's not ideal since it will slightly change the look of the button, but you can work around it by setting `BorderRadius = 1` for just Android, or all platforms, giving a slightly perceptible rounding to the corners.

[image: Examples of Buttons with various BorderWidth and BorderRadius values.]

### Workaround (code)

```
// HACK: fixes a bug where border doesn't work without a radius.
yourButton.BorderRadius = Device.OnPlatform<int>(iOS: 0, Android: 1, WinPhone: 0);
```

### Workaround (XAML)

```
<Button
    x:Name="YourButton"
    Text="Some Button Text"
    TextColor="Black"
    Clicked="OnClickedDiscover"
    BackgroundColor="Aqua"
    BorderColor="Red"
    BorderWidth="1">
    <Button.BorderRadius>
        <!-- HACK: fixes a bug where border doesn't work without a radius. -->
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Int32">
            <OnPlatform.Android>1</OnPlatform.Android>
        </OnPlatform>
    </Button.BorderRadius>
</Button>
```

Comment: For anyone wanting to play along at home, here's the bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=36031

Comment: This doesn't always work with thick borders, workaround is to keep increasing the radius on Android until you see the border. For instance if your BorderWidth = 6, you need to have at least BorderRadius = 3 for the border to show up....

Answer (score 1):

In Xamarin.Forms **2.5.0**, the patch has been reverted :

> "Revert "Fix border on android buttons (#941)" ([#1192](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/1192))"

You have to use a custom renderer for now...

<s>This bug has been fixed in the last [version](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/xamarin-forms/xamarin-forms-2.4/2.4.0-stable/) of Xamarin Forms 2.4.0 :</s>

<s>> 36031 - "Button border not drawn on Android without a BorderRadius" (PR)</s>

Answer (score 0):

in Android project go to MainActivity and change it to be inhereted 
from

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
```

to

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
```

now you won't have issue to use the Border

```
 <Button Text="test" TextColor="White" 
            BackgroundColor="#FFA733" BorderRadius="15" 
            BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

Comment: `FormsApplicationActivity` is obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Got the some problem. I did two things to solve it:

1. I don't set background color to the buttons for Android (only for iOS)

```xml
<Setter Property="BackgroundColor">
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
        <OnPlatform.iOS>Transparent</OnPlatform.iOS>
    </OnPlatform>
</Setter>
```

2. Manually setting a background drawable to the buttons

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">
  <stroke android:width="2px" android:color="#ffffff" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I found this solution, don't know why is working but it works.**

In PCL

```
namespace xxx.Renderers
{
    public class WhiteButton : Button
    {
        public WhiteButton()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Then you have to make the render in android and **DO NOTHING**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(WhiteButton), typeof(WhiteButtonRenderer))]
namespace xxxx.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class WhiteButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                var newElement = e.NewElement as WhiteButton;

                if (newElement != null)
                {

                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Then you only have to call instantiate the button and do the border that you want

```
    var myButton = new WhiteButton()
    {
        BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
        TextColor = Color.White,
        Text = "Desconectarse",
        BorderRadius = 45/2,//rounded border Heightbutton/2
        BorderWidth = 2,
        BorderColor = Color.White
    };
```

If nobody knows why is working please explain me , I have tried the same but with no render only using the class Button normally and if I do this I don't get the expected result.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16845037)

Comment: Yes, is not an answer, but it works so it is a temporally solution.

Answer (score 0):

in Android project create ButtonRenderer and paste code

```
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (Control != null)
        {
            var roundableShape = new GradientDrawable();
            roundableShape.SetShape(ShapeType.Rectangle);
            roundableShape.SetStroke((int) Element.BorderWidth,Element.BorderColor.ToAndroid());
            roundableShape.SetColor(Element.BackgroundColor.ToAndroid());
            roundableShape.SetCornerRadius(Element.BorderRadius * Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
            Control.Background = roundableShape;
            Control.TransformationMethod = null;
            Control.Elevation = 0;
        }
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
    }
```

[image]