# Border being ignored on Android - Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am attempting to build a circular button with a green border using Xamarin.Forms, using a method that I have used on previous projects by adding a BorderRadius, BorderColour etc values to the Button element.

Please consider the following code:

```
Button goButton = new Button
{
    Text = "GO!",
    TextColor = Color.White,
    FontSize = 75,
    HeightRequest = 200,
    WidthRequest = 200,
    BorderRadius = 100,
    BorderWidth = 10,
    BorderColor = Color.Green,
    BackgroundColor = Color.Red
};
```

The above code gives me the following, undesired output:

[image]

I have tried re-writing in XAML and had the same issue, I have also checked that my version of Xamarin (and NuGet Xamarin.forms packages) are up to date. However on the iOS version, everything looks correct (first time for everything I suppose!)

Any assistance in finding the problem and fixing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

**Suggested Edit:**

Please find below my styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
    <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
    </style>

    <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
    <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

        <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

        <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette -->

        <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>

        <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>

        <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for     colorControlActivated
     which is used to tint widgets -->
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>

        <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
     colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

        <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bordered `Button`s work fine for me... maybe try some more reasonable values:

```
Button button = new Button {
    BorderWidth = 1,
    BorderColor = Color.Green,
    BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
    Text = "GO!",
    TextColor = Color.White,
}
```

That is all I have in my `Button`s and the border shows up ok. Wondering if the `BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent` will make a difference for you.

*Edit: Adding comment as answer. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38455653/3850012) post, adding a completely empty custom renderer for the `Button` may help:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Button), typeof(GenericButtonRenderer))]

namespace Express.CustomRenderers {
    public class GenericButtonRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ButtonRenderer { }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get the exact same issue, I originally had transparent and moved it to red so it shows clearer for the screenshot.

Comment: @Aphire I am going to assume it is an issue with the Android theme and/or styles you have added. Maybe post the `Styles.xml` code you have in your `/values/` or `/values-21/` directories.

Comment: @Aphire Could you try updating to the latest version of Xamarin Forms in your projects to see if that helps? I do see a bug or two about related issues.

Comment: First of all, thanks for sticking with this, I appreciate it. Secondly I have a PCL, all of which are on 2.3.3.168, which I believe is the latest stable version released.

Comment: @Aphire Np, I definitely understand how frustrating Android UI can be, much less Android UI in Xamarin Forms. What if you added `BorderRadius = 1`? From Forms documentation, the `Button.BackgroundColor` must be a non-default value, so that should be covered at least.

Comment: I have in the past 5 minutes found out what the issue is, it appears the reference to AppCompat is what is causing the button to render incorrectly, I am just trying to figure out a way to keep my theme working, while not using AppCompat. Once I actually understand the problem in a bit more detail, I shall attempt to post an answer, more info can be found here https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=37210#c4 Should you want to take a look yourself, thanks!

Comment: @Aphire Nice find! Did not see that one. I wonder if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38455653/3850012) person is using material or not. Might be worth a shot.

Comment: That's perfect, the custom renderer allowed me to keep my current theme all intact. Thanks very much for sharing this, If you place that as an answer, I will happily accept.