# Xamarin Forms: ImageButton border ignored on Android

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, imagebutton

I have a `StackLayout` containing some `ImageButton`s, the buttons have a `BorderWidth` of 5.

On UWP, the border appears with the image scaled to fit inside. On Android, the border doesn't appear at all, and the image flows into it space.

UWP (correct):

[image: UWP]

Android (no border):
[image: Android]

My XAML looks like this

```
  <StackLayout 
    x:Name="titlebar"
    Orientation="Horizontal"
    BackgroundColor="{x:DynamicResource TitleBarColor}">

    ...

    <ImageButton
      x:Name="menu"
      HeightRequest="25" WidthRequest="25"
      HorizontalOptions="End"
      BorderWidth="5"
      BackgroundColor="{x:DynamicResource TitleBarColor}"
      Source="{local:ImageResource CloudTest.Assets.icons.more_menu_white.png}"
      Clicked="OnMenuClicked" />
  </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Have you already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40868466/border-being-ignored-on-android-xamarin-forms)?

Comment: I just looked at it. I'm not sure how it is relevant. That's using the Android SDK, not Xamarin Forms.

Answer (score 1):

In Android, I've found that it only works if you set both `BorderWidth` and `BorderColor`(could not `Transparent`).

and you also could set the `Padding` or `Margin`to the ImageButton to achieve to the effect.

```
<ImageButton
  x:Name="menu"
  HeightRequest="25" WidthRequest="25"
  HorizontalOptions="End"
  Padding ="5"  //or Margin ="5"
  BackgroundColor="{x:DynamicResource TitleBarColor}"
  Source="{local:ImageResource CloudTest.Assets.icons.more_menu_white.png}"
  Clicked="OnMenuClicked" />
```

**Update** (The yellow area is your ImageButton):

When using `Margin`,refers to the distance between the control and a sibling control :

[image]

`Padding` ,refers to the internal content of the control, such as the margin of the text/image distance from the control

[image]

so when you use the padding,you will see the space inside the image and when you use the margin,the space outside the image .

Comment: Padding: yes, that got me closer. Thanks ! There now is a space around the icon, but the proportions are wrong. Measuring the screenshots, I now have 7 px for the borders and 46 for the icon. In percent, that's 12, 76, 12. However, what I specified should be (in percent) 20, 60, 20 (which it is on UWP). Do you have any further ideas ?

Comment: I did another experiment, with margins. I set the margins to 5, changed the image HeightRequest to 15, and set the BackgroundColor to dark blue. It worked ! What a clumsy workaround, but I'm very happy you suggested using a non transparent background.

Comment: Actually, it works with a transparent background, too. So, apparently Margin works, but Padding and BorderWidth do not.

Comment: @PeriHartman yes ,i give an explanation in the update above.

Comment: The problem I now have, using Margin, is that it won't respond to clicks in the margin area. That makes for a lower quality UX.

Comment: @PeriHartman If you're using margin, the margin  area doesn't belong to your imageButton, so it won't respond to your imageButton's click.Instead if using padding then the spacing belongs to the ImageButton.Maybe you could try to use padding with a small value like 2px or 3px.

Comment: I tried padding. But the behavior is poor. It's width is inconsistent on each platform, meaning multiple copies of each xaml file.

Comment: Maybe that's the difference between the platforms.

Comment: No. It's buggy. Each platform should maintain the same proportions. I can forgive the scale factor being off, but not the proportions.

Comment: @PeriHartman Maybe you could try to use CustomRenderer to custom the control.

Comment: Actually, I'm in process of trying out SyncFusion, to see how well their control implementations work. I could effectively write my own control(s) but if someone else has done it, it makes more sense to take advantage of their work.